# InterfaceError in PooledDB?

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, python-2.7

I have a multi-thread program in python 2.7 using Mysql.In my multithread program the common
function for the threads is `process_submissions`. In that I create dedicated connection
using `conn=pool.dedicated_connection()`.The function `process_submissions` in turn passes
this connection `conn` to another function `rt_scripts` which queries on a table(using the connection passed to it) and returns to `process_submissions`.But I get the following error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
   self.run()
   File "worker_with_threads3.py", line 20, in run
   process_submission(self.name,self.q)
   File "worker_with_threads3.py", line 47, in process_submission
  cursor.execute(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/DBUtils-1.1-py2.7.egg/DBUtils    /SteadyDB.py", line 552, in tough_method
  result = method(*args, **kwargs) # try to execute
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 314, in execute
res = self.db().protocol.cmd_query(stmt)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 136, in deco
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 479, in cmd_query
return self.handle_cmd_result(self.conn.recv())
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 463, in handle_cmd_result
return self._handle_resultset(buf)[0:2]
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 62, in call
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 126, in call
return func(*args,**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 408, in _handle_resultset
fields.append(self._pkt_parse_field(buf))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 126, in call
return func(*args,**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 289, in _pkt_parse_field
(buf,field['db']) = utils.read_lc_string(buf)
 File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/utils.py", line 170, in read_lc_string
if buf[0] == '\xfb':
 InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation; string index out of range
```

What could be the reason , does passing connection like this create any problem or is it
something else??

Comment: Now I don't pass the db connection instead I create another one in the rt_scripts fucntion and close it before returning to the process_submissions this solved the problem but I still don't know why there is error in passing as it is also the same thing !!!!!